# How to use python office365-rest-client API update sharepoint list item person field with multiple users?

Tags: python, rest, office365, office365api

I am trying to use office365-rest-python-client library to update SharePoint list items person/grouop field with multiple user values. The example I found here (https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/listitems/set_lookup_field_value.py) does not quite solve the problem. I can get the site users and parse their ids or other user properties, just need the right syntax to update a (multi) persons field.

```
me = ctx.web.current_user
# items[0].set_property("AssignedTo", FieldUserValue(me.id)).update().execute_query()
# items[0].set_property("AssignedTo", FieldUserValue.from_user(me)).update().execute_query()
```